# Given number of base stations and users , how can I accociate each user to the nearest base station by matlab?

Tags: matlab

I deployed the BSs and Users randomly according to Binomial Point Process, and I assumed to connect each user to nearest BS. So, how can I accociate these users in matlab.
thanks in advance

```
ro=500; %  radius of the layout circle 
NumBSs=10;  %  Number of Base stations
NumUEs=50;   %Number of users
center=[0 0]; % center of the circle
theta_BSs=2*pi*(rand(NumPoints,1)); % distributed random number of Base stations
g = 0.5 * ro + 0.5 * ro * rand(NumBSs,1); 
PosBSs_x=center(1)+g.*cos(theta_BSs);
PosBSs_y=center(2)+g.*sin(theta_BSs); 

theta1 = rand(NumUEs, 1) * 2*pi; % distributed random number of Users
r1 = ro * sqrt(rand(NumUEs, 1));
PosUE = [r1 .* cos(theta1(:)) + center(1),r1 .* sin(theta1(:)) + center(2)]; 

% Initial plot objects
hfig = figure('Color', 'w');
hax=axes('parent',hfig);
% Plot of deploying  points
hdots=plot(PosBSs_x(:,1),PosBSs_y(:,1),'bp',PosUE(:,1),PosUE(:,2),'r.','MarkerSize', 12);       
grid on
hold(hax, 'on')    
axis(hax, 'equal')
% Plot the layout as circles
t = linspace(0, 2*pi);
plot(ro * cos(t) + center(1),ro * sin(t) + center(2))
```

Comment: Please post code that can be run as is. The variable `NmuPoints` is undefined

Comment: This question is not entirely clear. The code does not run out of the box. NumPoints is undefined in the posted snippet. It could be that what you are looking for is how to use data structures in matlab. Look up the documentation for cells. It might help you.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

```
distances = hypot(PosBSs_x-PosUE(:,1).', PosBSs_y-PosUE(:,2).');
[~, assigned_BS] = min(distances, [], 1);
```

A matrix of distances from all base stations to all users is computed using [`hypot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hypot.html) with [implicit expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/). Then [`min`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html) is applied along the appropriate dimension, and its second output provides the index of the minimizing distance.

As a check, the assignment of users to base stations can be added to the plot:

```
plot([PosUE(:,1) PosBSs_x(assigned_BS)].', [PosUE(:,2) PosBSs_y(assigned_BS)].', ...
      'color',  [.5 .5 .5])
```

[image]

Comment: Can I deploy ONE ground BS randomly at the center [0 0] , and let the users consider that ground BS same as as other BSs, so some of nearest users will connect to ground BS and other users will be connected to other BSs? @LuisMendo

Comment: @omaraljubory Sorry, I don't understand your question. The specific position of the base station doesn't matter; the code will treat it like any other base station

Comment: @LuisMenndo first many thanks for your responses, well I deployed the Base stations (BSs=Nodes) and ground base station (gNB= single Node at the center [0 0] seperately) , so when I tried to gather thier coordinates to let the users that located near to the center connect to gNB and the other users which are located away from the center connect to the BSs as you told me in the previous answers,  
 So, I got an error " Dimensions of arrays being concatenated are not consistent" would you help me with this issue ?

Comment: I’m not sure how to help there, sorry. Check the dimensions, the error is very clear

Comment: Can we only assign the RED points that are distance 100m from the BLUE stars, BUT if the RED points away from BLUE stars more than 100m shouldn't be assigned or Is there a way to assign the RED points which are located within the BLUE stars range (assume blue stars have range (as circle) is 100m raduis) ?

Comment: @omaraljubory I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I suggest you phrase it more carefully and use a new question for that, as the new requirement seems to deviate from the original question

Comment: Actually I made a question but I didn't get any response yet. this is the link of my question if you would like to help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71120202/can-we-assign-the-users-that-located-within-the-range-of-blue-stars-and-black-do

Comment: this is the link of my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71120202/can-we-assign-the-users-that-located-within-the-range-of-blue-stars-and-black-do